# Avoiding Possible Precision Loss with a Simple Moving Average

Tags: algorithm, floating-point-precision, moving-average

Suppose we had a basic moving average function that was keeping track of the sum. For example:

```
Queue values;
double sum;

double CalcSMA(double next) {
    values.push(next);
    sum -= values.pop();
    sum += next;
    return sum / SMA_LENGTH;
}
```

One example of how this could break down would be if our window was 5 wide that we fed it something like:
`2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1E100, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2`.
The output would then be `2, 2, 2, 2E99, 2E99, 2E99, 2E99, 2E99, 0, 0, 0`.

Even if the sum isn't quite that dramatically off, there still could be quite reasonable instances where a small loss in precision could make the sum artificially increase by a tiny amount. Over a long period of time, this could add up and become an issue.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to work around the loss in precision?

EDIT: note that this function is designed to work O(1). That is necessary. So, recalculating each time won't work: the window is too large.

Comment: I don't understand your output. Shouldn't it be more like `2, 2, 2, 2E99, 2E99, 2E99, 2E99, 2E99, 0, 0, 0, 0` (where `0` stands for a number near `0`). Surely the algorithm subtracts the `1E100` once it goes out of frame, although after that things are not very accurate. You almost need a re-reading of the entire queue, a kind of recalibration.

Comment: You are correct. I fixed the question.

Comment: You can estimate the worst case error of the sum with the usual ULP/epsilon analysis and re-sum the buffer when the error becomes too large (consult a good text on numerical computation if you don't know these terms). Or you can use arbitrary precision (bignum) math.

Comment: @Gene Arbitrary precision won't work indefinitely though. Error Analysis could work though.

Comment: Actually, arbitrary precision should be fine if you implement properly. See, for example, Shewchuk's algorithm (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/393090/). Since every value eventually cancels itself out, and every value is a precise double, the expansion cannot have more elements than the window size (although it is likely to have a lot less, particularly for large windows).

Comment: True, I forgot that the values cancel. But I guess the argument could then be made that worst case is O(n). (I think)

Comment: @jay: yes, the worst case is O(n), as I said in my comment. But it's *probably* a lot less, whereas recomputing the sum every time is always O(n). Anyway, Shewchuk's paper is worth a read (pdf here: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/robustr.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could recalculate a fresh sum over every SMA_LENGTH values to stop the errors accumulating:

```
Queue values;
double sum = 0.0;
double freshsum = 0.0;
int count = 0;

double CalcSMA(double next) {
    values.push(next);
    sum -= values.pop();
    sum += next;
    freshsum += next;
    if(++count == SMA_LENGTH)
    {
        sum = freshsum;
        freshsum = 0.0;
        count = 0;
    } 
    return sum / SMA_LENGTH;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What samgak proposed doesn't actually guarantee good averages if you constantly provide it with evil values.

You can use [Neumaier's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm#Further_enhancements) algorithm to generate accurate results in O(1) time. Something like this:

```
const double SMA_LENGTH = 5;
Queue values;
double sum = 0.0;
double correction = 0.0;

static void Neumaier(double value, ref double sum, ref double correction)
{
    var t = sum + value;
    if (Math.Abs(sum) >= Math.Abs(value))
        correction += (sum - t) + value;
    else
        correction += (value - t) + sum;
    sum = t;
}

double CalcSMA(double next)
{
    Neumaier(-values.pop(), ref sum, ref correction);
    Neumaier(next, ref sum, ref correction);
    values.push(next);
    return (sum + correction) / SMA_LENGTH;
}
```

If you have huge sequences, you can reset the window every 10^15 or so additions. This is because, with double precision, the algorithm starts losing accuracy after about 10^16 additions.

On the other hand, Neumaier is more complex so it is probably slower.

Comment: While for a fixed length sum, Neumaier or Kahan summation are more accurate, @samgak's answer has a bounded error for the moving average, your approach does not.

Comment: @Joe Yes, which is why I mentioned resetting the window, like samgak does. The difference is, Neumaier will actually provide accurate numbers within the given window. (Kahan isn't applicable because it assumes small elements)